# Setting MySQL session variable with sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy, set

I have a MySQL query that gives the error:
"Error Code: 1104. The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay"

To run this successfully in MySQL Workbench, I simply execute:

```
SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...;
```

This runs both statements at once - SQL_BIG_SELECTS is set to 1 which allows the query below it to run.

Now I want to access the result of this query in python and store it in a pandas dataframe.  I'm using mysqlalchemy to connect to the database.

I tried running the SET and SELECT at the same time, the same way I am able to successfully in MySQL Workbench:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def query001():
  engine_fdb = create_engine('...connection string...')

  sql_cmd = """
    SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...;
  """

  df = pd.read_sql(sql_cmd, engine_fdb)
```

The last line generates an error: "sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically."  I'm having a hard time understanding the information I've found on why this happens - I feel I'm in over my head.

In python, how can I query a MySQL database, first setting the option SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 and then executing a query with that option turned on?

Comment: Please post your complete code. It is confusing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I revised the question to try to simplify it. There is no more code to show except the connection string and the specifics of the query.  The specific query doesn't matter in relation to this question except for the fact that it exceeds the MAX_JOIN_SIZE of MySQL.  Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409392/set-session-in-a-sqlalchemy-session-object), see proposed solutions there