# how to set session property when executing pd.to_sql? {error:"Required field 'numDVs' is unset! }

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, presto

there is issue when insert dataframe data to presto db.

error message is

```
{'message': "Required field 'numDVs' is unset! Struct:LongColumnStatsData(lowValue:0, highValue:2, numNulls:0, numDVs:0),
'errorCode': 16777216, 
'errorName': 'HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR', 
'errorType': 'EXTERNAL' ..."
```

i think

```
SET SESSION COLLECT_COLUMN_STATISTICS_ON_WRITE = FALSE
```

should be executed before inserting data.
but i can't find way to do.
is there any way to set session property, before execute pd.to_sql?

```
from pyhive import presto
result.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

table format

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
similarity DOUBLE,
cluster INTEGER,
member_cnt INTEGER,
member_list VARCHAR,
mean_similarity DOUBLE,
ym VARCHAR(6)
)
WITH (format = 'ORC', PARTITIONED_BY = ARRAY['ym'])
```

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514796/setting-mysql-session-variable-with-sqlalchemy-in-python, which unfortunately hasn't been answered as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set session properties by `session_props` as below.

```py
from pyhive import presto
cursor = presto.connect('localhost', session_props={'hive.collect_column_statistics_on_write': 'false'}).cursor()
```